# Geolocation on React Native ALWAYS times out?

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native

I must have been googling for at least 3 hours now and absolutely nothing that I've found on the internet has helped. Some common suggestions were to remove the 3rd callback on the `getCurrentPosition()` function, or setting `highAccuracy` to false. Using telnet to fix a geo location. I set the correct permission in my manifest file and I just can not seem to receive anything other than a `Request Timed Out, Code: 3` error...

Here is the code for getting location (which I render on another component in a separate file...

```
class GeolocationExample extends React.Component {
state = { position: [] };

componentDidMount() {
 navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(
    (location) => {
      console.log(location);
      this.setState({position: location});
     },
     (error) => console.log(error)
   );
 }



render() {
 return (
  <View>
    <Text>
      <Text style={styles.title}>Initial position: </Text>
      {this.state.position}
    </Text>
  </View>
 );
}
}
```

I've been going at this for a while now so any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Can you confirm whether you are using an emulator or a real device?

Comment: @manosim emulator, ive tried changing the location mode to "battery saving", "high accuracy", and "device only" as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I faced the same problem few days back. Here is how I solved it.

In your emulator you should see an options menu on bottom. Click that. You will see a tab for location where you can enter the lat and long. Whenever you request location in your code, press send on the right. The send will only work when it is send after you have requested the location.

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I would start from the react-native documentation around [Geolocation](http://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/geolocation.html). They even provide a complete example on how to use it which should work as is.

Apart from this, I would also suggest checking that you have set the correct permissions in the AndroidManifest.xml. Make sure you restart the app once you've added the line below.

`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />`

Your code looks ok so maybe it's just the permissions?

Comment: Yeah my code is basically from their documentation, I've added the permission and restarted the app multiple times...just so baffled.